# Ext is not defined

Tags: asp.net, javascript, extjs, firebug

I'm trying to implement a TinyMCE plugin with ExtJs, with a demo as example, found here: [link](http://blogs.byte-force.com/xor/tinymce/).

This fails because I receive an "Ext is not defined" error in Firebug. I basically copied the example, I only used a newer version of Ext. First of all the css and scripts are included:

```
<link href="scripts/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="scripts/extjs/ext-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/miframe/miframe-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/ux/Ext.ux.TinyMCE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Firebug does not complain, all the scripts are found on the specified paths and are included.

[image: Firebug shows the scripts as OK]

Next I call the Ext function in the head of my aspx document,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Ready...");
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        console.log("set...");
        Ext.get("cmdOpen").on("click", function() {
            console.log("GO");
            var dlg = new Ext.Window({

//etc
</script>
```

The console.log("Ready...") shows up in the console, then the code breaks. There are four references to "Ext is not defined", in ext-all.js(), miframe-min.js(), Ext.ux.TinyMCE.js() and in the code in the .aspx file. (Default.aspx)

I did not alter any aspect of the included files, they are official releases.
Am I perhaps missing a statement somewhere? Or do I have to include other things still? I have honestly no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when including ext-all(-debug).js, you still need to include the ext-base.js file before that, otherwise you will get the "Ext is not defined error".  Not sure by your last comment if you are already past this or not, but I thought I would point it out.  Please see this page for complete details on how your includes should be set up:

http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:HTML_Page_Setup

Comment: I remember I read somewhere that ext-base was a standalone file... but when I looked up the include-sequence it indeed appeared to be a necessary file. After I included the ext-base my code worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

there is a firefox extension called "jsview", it allows you to see what scripts and css files are included on a page.

When navigating to [the link](http://blogs.byte-force.com/xor/tinymce/) you include at the top of your post and opening the ExtJs file, you'll notice that the example provided is using version 2.1 of the code.

The Ext.ux.TinyMCE v0.6 has a corresponding [blog post here](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24787). You will notice that it specifically requires:

- Firefox 2+, Opera 9+, MSIE 7
- **ExtJS 2.1**
- TinyMCE 3.1.0.1
- Ext.ux.ManagedIframePanel

Be aware that when plugging in a newer versions of the TinyMCE or ExtJs libraries, there *might* (read **will**) be breaking changes that you will then have to resolve. You could try scrape the files directly from the example to ensure you have a working version.

If you choose to use ExtJs v3+, get the latest components:
1) [ux.ManagedIframe](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=16590) has been maintained [more recently](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40961) and even upgraded for ExtJS 3.x [here](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=71961)
2) Read through the [ux.TinyMce thread](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24787) and download the latest version. I think it's 0.7b. If you're still having problems, that's probably the best place to find answers.

Comment: I located ExtJs 2.3 on the official website and gave that a try. This does indeed work. However I have some other issues now, but these appear to happen on the demo site as well.

Answer (score 1):

copy the lib folder in your eclipse workspace`s exjts project folder and just give the relative paths, is should than work

Answer (score 0):

Go to ExtJs website and make sure you download and included all the necessary files and IN ORDER,also using a newer version might break the code.
try it with simpler examples and only reference the ext stuff and see if it loads